# Reference on checking result for a third order numerical EDO

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods

Consider the following differential equation
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime\prime\prime}=xy\qquad\qquad y(0)=1,\:\:y^{\prime}(0)=0,\:\:y^{\prime\prime}(0)=1.
\end{equation}

Using the third order Runge-Kutta method I found that $y(1/2)\cong 1,117311159$.

Is there any sort of online calculator where I can check if this result is correct? I've tried wolfram but it looks like the numerical ODE solver only does the first order ones.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NDSolve[{y'''[x] == x y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, y''[0] == 1}, 
  y[x], {x, 0, 1}] /. x -> 0.5
```

in Mathematica gets the answer

```
{{y[0.5] -> 1.12767}}
```

Comment: Right, thanks. Btw, I forgot to mention that I used $h=0.25$. I don't understand much about Mathematica so I'm not really sure: did you use $h=0.1$?

Comment: No, I did not use any specific steps, as far as I am aware by default Mathematica has an adaptive algorithm, which chooses the step depending on the properties of your functions.